# iOS - Sending Touch Events To A DFPBannerView from a Custom ScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, google-dfp

I am trying to implement DFP ads into my iOS application within a custom scroll view.

I have a number of view controllers within a horizontal custom UIScrollView, and after a few pages I have a DFPBannerView the size of the full UIScrollView frame. My custom scroll view overrides the touchesBegan:, touchesMoved:, etc methods of the UIScrollView because of some unique behavior I want to get out of it. My problem arises when the user tries to click on the DFPBannerView. Instead of the banner view receiving the touch, the scroll view does instead. Since apparently you can't send touch events directly to a DFPBannerView I end up stuck with nothing to do with that touch event.

Is there any way around this? Perhaps some way to disable touches (but not swipes) on the custom UIScrollView when the view controller with the DFPBannerView is showing?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Explain the "custom" scroll view behavior. I'll bet a refactor of that behavior might solve the problem indirectly.

Comment: Yeah, a refactor is definitely in order. Currently the custom scroll view detects a touch, records the initial positions, then as the user moves their finger it calculates their direction in the touchesMoved: method and determines whether to do a normal horizontal scroll or whether to pass a vertical scroll onto a view which rests on top of the scroll view. Similarly if the user does not move their finger any significant distance, it recognizes it as a single touch and passes that event over to the view controller that contains the scroll view.